# Why might I have a Get request showing every 3 seconds with .net Core Razor with Application Insights?

Tags: iis, azure-application-insights, razor-pages, .net-core-3.0

I have deployed a Razor Application to IIS which uses Application Insights.

In development this works fine and logs as expected.
When I've deployed to servers, there is a get request every couple of seconds showing to the Application Start Page i.e. GET /Index

Is this normal for .net Core and the Default setup? I wouldn't have thought so.
I am trying to find out if there is anything external from our Load balancers checking "is it up?"

However the ip is 0.0.0.0 (local), Request URL https://unknown-host/

Anyone know what this might be and how to get rid of this please?
I know I can disable Get requests from being logged but I don't want it that quiet.

Many thanks.
Paul

Comment: It sounds like this could be from a Load balancer although I would have expected to see its IP address. Is there a way to filter these out these healthchecks?

Comment: Azure defaults the request IP in Application Insights to 0.0.0.0 for privacy/data protection reasons. You can change that in the settings and see who the caller is. As Paul already pointed out, probably some service performing health checks.

Answer (score 0):

Loadbalancer typically send some headers/user-agent, and can be identified with that. You can write a telemetry initializer to attach headers/user-agent to the telemetry, and inspect them to identify which loadbalancer/health check is triggering this. Once that is identified, you can use TelemetryProcessor to filter them out or mark them as synthetic (and filter in UI) etc.

("User-Agent" is the header you need to look for.)

The IP Address is removed and replaced with 0.0.0.0. This is the default behavior but can be changed to store the full ip by following this doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-collection#overriding-default-behavior